# Populate a combo box with a string array in a user form

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to solve an issue with a combo box, where I don't want the listed options to create another double every time the macro is executed, which happens if the AddItem property is only used to populate the combo box. The project is to list 12 months in a dropdown menu within a user form, with the goal being to let the user display that table in print preview mode (the accompanying worksheet has a table for each month). I wrote a string array for the months and then told it to populate the combo box with the AddItem property in a loop. To wit:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim strMonth(0 To 11) As String

strMonth(0) = "Print April Table"
strMonth(1) = "Print May Table"
strMonth(2) = "Print June Table"
strMonth(3) = "Print July Table"
strMonth(4) = "Print August Table"
strMonth(5) = "Print September Table"
strMonth(6) = "Print October Table"
strMonth(7) = "Print November Table"
strMonth(8) = "Print December Table"
strMonth(9) = "Print January Table"
strMonth(10) = "Print February Table"
strMonth(11) = "Print March Table"

Dim mthPosition As Long

For mthPosition = LBound(strMonth) To UBound(strMonth)
    UserForm13.ComboBox1.AddItem strMonth(mthPosition)

    Next mthPosition

With UserForm13.ComboBox1

    .Style = fmStyleDropDownList
    End With

    UserForm13.Show
End Sub
```

For some reason, I get an error at the AddItem line saying that VBA could not find the specified object, even though the path is specified... the same thing happens if the code is run under a routine for the ComboBox or tested in a separate routine.

I appreciate your help in this respect.

Comment: This code is in another userform?

Comment: Are you sure your other form is actually called `UserForm13` and that the combo box on it is actually called `ComboBox1`?

Comment: Robin, indeed - I checked the names of things and there was no issue I could find.

Comment: Thomas - the project is divided into modules...this code is in its own module and the userform's components call the code as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you check for actual userforms and combobox names, you can try this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim strMonth(1 To 12) As String

strMonth(1) = "Print April Table"
strMonth(2) = "Print May Table"
strMonth(3) = "Print June Table"
strMonth(4) = "Print July Table"
strMonth(5) = "Print August Table"
strMonth(6) = "Print September Table"
strMonth(7) = "Print October Table"
strMonth(8) = "Print November Table"
strMonth(9) = "Print December Table"
strMonth(10) = "Print January Table"
strMonth(11) = "Print February Table"
strMonth(12) = "Print March Table"

With UserForm13
    With .ComboBox1
        .Clear
        .List = strMonth
        .Style = fmStyleDropDownList
    End With
    .Show
End With
Unload UserForm13

End Sub
```

Comment: ^This suggestion works beautifully. I did not know about using the .List property. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. If I fullfilled your question please mark the answer as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Don't need an array for this (though that's likely not the cause of your error:

```
Dim m As Long, s As String

For m = 1 To 12
    s = "Print " & MonthName(((m + 2) Mod 12) + 1) & " Table"
    UserForm13.ComboBox1.AddItem s
Next m
```

Comment: Tim, thank you much. Your solution works even better from the point of view of being a more effective use of the code...I'll probably fall back on it on this project. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try Robins suggestion as it is the most likely solution if that is correct then the object it is complaining about must be array.

The follow should do the same thing as your function you could test that.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
   With UserForm13.ComboBox1
      .AddItem "Print April Table"
      .AddItem "Print May Table"
      .AddItem "Print June Table"
      .AddItem "Print July Table"
      .AddItem "Print August Table"
      .AddItem "Print September Table"
      .AddItem "Print October Table"
      .AddItem "Print November Table"
      .AddItem "Print December Table"
      .AddItem "Print January Table"
      .AddItem "Print February Table"
      .AddItem "Print March Table"
      .Style = fmStyleDropDownList
   End With
   UserForm13.Show
End Sub
```

If it errors on the line "With UserForm13.ComboBox1" then Robin is right the user-form or combo box must have another name.

Good luck

Comment: Andrew, this was exactly what I had earlier, and it was what generated doubles and triples of the month names in the menu every time I run the code; the way it's set up is that a button on the spreadsheet calls this sub when it's clicked and you go ahead and print whatever monthly table you want.

Comment: If you are getting duplicates then clear it before you add the values ComboBox1.Clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running ComboBox1_Change() event from Userform13 then your will get this error

> Form already displayed; can't show modally

Unless you set `Userform13's ShowModal` to false on Userform13's Property page.