# Range columns to fill combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fill a ComboBox with column names.

For every option I try I get:

> Error 380 Runtime RowSource.

In forums this seemed to work, but I need it for columns.

```vb
ComboBox1.Value = "Please Select an employee from the dropdown"
ComboBox1.RowSource = "Sheet1!A3:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

The blue headers are the ones I need in the comboBox, from A3:J3
[image: Headers in blue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the picture, it looks like your data is in a [List Object](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables). If so, it is very easy to grab the Headers from the list object, and turn them into an array. Once you have an array, you can insert the array into the ComboBox List like `myComboBox.List = myArray`.

```vb
Sub Example()
    'Get the List Object
    Dim myList As ListObject
    Set myList = Sheet1.ListObjects("List1") 'CHANGE "List1" TO MATCH YOUR TABLE'S NAME
    
    'Get the Headers
    Dim ListHeaders As Range
    Set ListHeaders = myList.HeaderRowRange
    
    'Create an empty Array
    Dim Headers() As String
    ReDim Headers(ListHeaders.Cells.Count - 1)
    
    'Fill the Array
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To ListHeaders.Cells.Count - 1
        Headers(i) = ListHeaders.Cells(i + 1)
    Next
    
    'Put the Array into the ComboBox
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Headers
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Heey, i tried your code, it works great, however the client still has a problem with the 380 error, runtime 380 error, Userform runtime error 380- could not set the rowsource property - fix?

Comment: @RaúlPalmaKaschel My answer does not try to set the rowsource property, it specifically avoids trying to do that. If you have an array, put it into the `List` property, not `RowSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this solution as a starting point for loading your data in a ComboBox: [Populate a combo box with a string array in a user form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045594/populate-a-combo-box-with-a-string-array-in-a-user-form)

Ignore the UserForm part, as it might not be relevant in this scenario.

I recommend that you make a range object out of the column headings, load them into an array and then load them into a combo box, in the event that these headings might change at some moment.